# Spring Batch: How to identify job failing at which step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. My job is failing sometimes at different
step and sometimes at different step and also when I try to debug it
return completed.
I have no idea what is going on. Can anybody please guide me for this weird behavior of Spring batch job. And also if there is any way 
to find out at what step the job fails in overall job.

> I am using SQL Loader in the batch. So sometimes it gives error
>   related to SQLLoader also ERROR 1: SQL*Loader-951: Error calling
>   once/load initialization ERROR 2: SQL*Loader-941: Error during
>   describe of table ABC_TABLE
>
> This 2 errors I got on random run of JOb.
>
> And at sometimes it shows no ERROR the SQLLoader shows as
>   INFOCOMPLETED status And still the job fails.

Comment: What error you get when it failed ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I have updated the question with answer to your question.

Comment: We are not sure what the job is doing? Is it extracting bulk data from database? Also, the errors pasted by you are custom errors written in application. If you could add the stacktrace, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue.
In my JobExceutionListener -> afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) method 
I added log for

```
> logger.info("\n\n Job ends........."+"\t jobexcution
> failure--"+jobExecution.getFailureExceptions()+"\n\t
> StepExceutions=="+jobExecution.getStepExecutions());
```

It shows me the exception and also the step at where its giving the issue and then after debugging it I was able to get the issue.

Comment: This is not right way to log exception. If exception is thrown during job and is not skippable, it is properly logged by Spring Batch. You posted too little info about your job definition. What is SQLLoader? Post your log.